# Como alterar um elemento dentro de um arquivo less?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, less

```
@fundo:#fff; //como alterar isso, externamente com javascript 
@texto:rgb(94, 135, 176); //preciso mudar essa propriedade dinamicamente. 

.wrapper{
    background-color:@fundo;
}
nav a:hover{
    color:darken(@fundo, 30%); 
}
nav a{
    color:darken(@fundo, 20%); 
}
.active>a, .well, .active:after, .navbar-toggle{
    color:@texto; 
}
.well{
    background-color:darken(@fundo, 5%); 
    border-color:darken(@fundo, 10%);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se a sua folha de estilos LESS estiver sendo processada no browser (e não enviada como CSS do servidor) você pode sim alterar as variáveis em *tempo de execução*. O arquivo não será carregado novamente, mas ele será recompilado.

Sua folha de estilos Less deve estar sendo carregada no browser, então você deve ter algo como:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="estilo.less" />
```

Depois de carregar a folha de estilos, você deve carregar o `less.js`:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/1.6.3/less.min.js"></script>
```

(você também pode baixar de https://github.com/less)

Com isso você pode usar o objeto global `less` que permite obter várias informações da folha de estilos, e alterar variáveis. Esse objeto e seus componentes não são muito bem documentados, mas dá para descobrir muita coisa via introspecção no console do JavaScript.

Um dos recursos documentados é a alteração de variáveis, que você pode realizar através da função `modifyVars()` que recebe um mapa de variáveis que devem ser alteradas:

```
less.modifyVars({
  '@fundo': '#eee',
  '@texto': 'rgb(255, 135, 176)'
});
```

Veja mais sobre isto [aqui](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser)

Há muito mais que se pode fazer com less no browser, mas muita coisa não está documentada, portanto pode ser que mude no futuro. Dá para extrair dados de uma folha de estilos Less que esteja no seu domínio (independente de ela estar ou não sendo usada na sua página) com o `less.Parser`, que você pode criar assim:

```
var parser = new(less.Parser);
```

E depois processar usando `parse()`:

```
parser.parse("@v1: 5pt; @v2: 10pt; h1 {font-size: @v1}", function (e, tree) { ... });
```

Por exemplo, o script abaixo extrai todas as variáveis de `folha-de-estilo.less` e as lista dentro de um bloco `<ul id="varlist"></id>` que tenha na página.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var parser = new(less.Parser);
    $.get( "/styles/less/folha-de-estilo.less", function( data ) {
        parser.parse(data, function (e, tree) {
            var variables = tree.variables();
            console.log(variables)
            for (i in variables) {
                var name = variables[i].name;
                var value = variables[i].value.toCSS(); // FALHA se variavel contiver expressao
                $("#varlist").append("<li>"+name + ":" + value+"</li>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Só funciona para variáveis Less que tenham valores CSS dentro (não podem ter expressões). Isto pode ser útil para aproveitar valores usados em scripts.

Comment: Nossa cara muito bom, era isso que precisava.

Comment: nem imaginava que era possível, +1

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível alterar uma variável do LESS com JavaScript. Antes de ser interpretado pelo browser, o LESS é compilado como CSS (que não tem suporte a variáveis), e as referências à variável são substituídas pelo respectivo valor.

O que você pode fazer por js é alterar os valores um a um.

Comment: Você tem alguma ideia de como posso alterar as cores do template, segue o exemplo http://plnkr.co/edit/1w7Y1W?p=preview

Comment: @WeslleyOliveira Em que situação você precisa alterar as cores? Precisa ser mesmo em js? E se você criar classes diferentes com as várias cores, e só trocar a classe via js? Ficaria mais simples.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mais é possível sim alterar as variáveis conforme resposta do @helderdarocha. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode tentar também criar um mixin para realizar o que precisa. Se caso for questões de paleta de cores de aconselho a usar as próprias funções do LESS.

Answer (score 0):

Como o @bfavaretto disse, não tem como alterar a variável LESS utilizando js, porém tendo um pouco de trabalho você pode alterar as propriedades para valores estáticos que seria, por exemplo, através de uma função:

```
function alteraTema(fundo,texto){
    $('.wrapper').css('background-color',fundo);
    $('nav a:hover').css('color',texto);
    $('nav a').css('color',texto);
    $('.active a, .well, .active:after, .navbar-toggle').css('color', texto);
    $('.well').css({
        'background-color':fundo
        ,'border-color':fundo
    });
}
```

E você pode simplesmente utilizar `alteraTema('#fff','#ccc');` por exemplo e estaria alterando seu tema como desejado.

## [Exemplo funcionando no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxfyL/1/)

Comment: é possível sim conforme resposta do nosso amigo @helderdarocha. Obrigado